# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider -> $routeProviderProvider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

> Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider

I am getting this error in my console when running my code. I have tried all the fixing mechanisms already. any of the ideas are not working fine.I am sharing my code here.

The functionality I need is if I click on a sub-menu item it should redirect to the proper page. and it should get the path from `action.json` file

**basePrductContoller.js**

```
App.controller("BaseProductController", ['$scope', '$sce', '$routeProvider', function ($scope, $sce, $routeProvider) {
    //some code here
    console.log('process_base_product()' + $routeProvider.json_url);

    $.getJSON("./api-data/" + $routeProvider.json_url, function (json) {
        $scope.data = json;
        console.log('JSON--', $scope.data);
        $scope.processdata();
    });

    result += '<form id="myform" action="http://building/dev-1/api/' + $routeProvider.post_method_url + '"  method="post" >';

    //code continues
}]);
```

**side menu.html**

```
<ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse">
    <span ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">
        <li>
            <a href="#base-product?{{item.path}}&{{item.apiPath}}" > {{item.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

**App.js**

```
var App = angular.module('EnergyFocusApp', ['ngRoute']);
App.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider


        .when('/base-product:json_url?:post_method_url?', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/base_product.html',
            controller: 'BaseProductController'
        })

});
```

**side nav controller**

```
App.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var itemsFactory = {
        itemDetails: function () {
            return $http({
                    url: "api-data/action.json",
                    method: "GET",
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
    return itemsFactory;

}]);


App.controller('SidenavController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function ($scope, itemsFactory) {

    console.log("side nav controller is being tested in the local host")
    var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.select = function (item) {
        $scope.selected = item;
    }
    $scope.selected = {};
}]);
```

**action.json**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Product View",
        "path": "actions/product/view.json",
        "urlpath": "product_view?segment=product-view",
        "apiPath": "api/merchant_product_view",
        "methodType": "post"
    },
    {
        "title": "Product Add",
        "path": "actions/product/add.json",
        "urlpath": "product_add?segment=product_add",
        "apiPath": "api/merchant_product_add"
    },
    {
        "title": "Product Update",
        "path": "actions/product/update.json",
        "urlpath": "product_update?segment=product_update",
        "apiPath": "api/merchant_product_update"
    },
    {
        "title": "Product delete",
        "path": "actions/product/delete.json",
        "urlpath": "product_delete?segment=product_delete",
        "apiPath": "api/merchant_product_delete"
    }
]
```

**base product.html**

```
<div id="result" style="width:600px; text-transform: capitalize;" align="right"></div>
```

Comment: Are you minifying your files? Have you included the [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) scripts?

Comment: @George : -yes i have included the ngRoute in te app.module in app.js and referred to all the sample code but couldn't fix this

Comment: What I mean is have you done `<script src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>` in your HTML?

Comment: @George :  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js"></script> i included this script

Comment: is it enough?? @George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access\inject `providers` inside the `controller.`
So below line is causing your problem.

```
App.controller("BaseProductController", ['$scope', '$sce', '$routeProvider', function ($scope, $sce, $routeProvider) {..\\
```

you need to inject either of [`$route, $routeParams, $location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) in controller to play with routing.

Comment: @DeepakVijay: I don't know if you checked the link I include in my answer, there is plunker in that link. you can take that for example. [See this](https://plnkr.co/edit/fVWdahTQSeiGhAwY6S6P?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Like Anoop mentioned above, the routeprovider should be elsewhere. i.e. in ur config()

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
```

BTW: It would be wiser to use UI-router than ngRoute module as in UI-router, u can do much more things like adding child views to states, etc.

UI-router is a standard implementation in production env.

So, cleanse this part in your first base*.js file. 
If u want a json_url, try using a value() [if ur json-url is fixed], else use $location instead.